# Hide duplicate data or not required row in query

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have 2 tables

```
users

id,  name,    added_date
 1, 'name1', '2016-08-23 21:01:59'
 2, 'name2', '2016-08-23 21:01:59'
 3, 'name3', '2016-08-23 21:01:59'
 4, 'name4', '2016-08-23 21:01:59'

comments

day_added, comment,    user_id
'Mon'    , 'comment1',       3
'Tue'    , 'comment2',       3
'N/A'    , 'comment3',       3
'N/A'    , 'comment4',       4
```

Following is Query I am using.

```
SELECT id
     , name
     , DATE_FORMAT(users.added_date,'%a') today
     , added_date
     , day_added
     , comment
     , user_id
  FROM users 
  LEFT 
  JOIN comments 
    ON users.id = comments.user_id 
   AND (
       DATE_FORMAT(users.added_date,'%a') = comments.day_added 
       OR 
       comments.day_added = 'N/A'
       )
```

Which results like following

```
id, name,     today,  added_date,           day_added, comment   , user_id
 1, 'name1', 'Tue' , '2016-08-23 21:01:59', NULL     , NULL      , NULL
 2, 'name2', 'Tue' , '2016-08-23 21:01:59', NULL     , NULL      , NULL
 3, 'name3', 'Tue' , '2016-08-23 21:01:59', 'Tue'    , 'comment2', 3
 3, 'name3', 'Tue' , '2016-08-23 21:01:59', 'N/A'    , 'comment3', 3
 4, 'name4', 'Tue' , '2016-08-23 21:01:59', 'N/A'    , 'comment4', 4
```

I want my results like

```
id, name,     today,  added_date,           day_added, comment   , user_id
 1, 'name1', 'Tue' , '2016-08-23 21:01:59', NULL     , NULL      , NULL
 2, 'name2', 'Tue' , '2016-08-23 21:01:59', NULL     , NULL      , NULL
 3, 'name3', 'Tue' , '2016-08-23 21:01:59', 'Tue'    , 'comment2', 3
 4, 'name4', 'Tue' , '2016-08-23 21:01:59', 'N/A'    , 'comment4', 4
```

Problem is user_id 3 which has 2 rows with day_added Tue and 'N/A':

I want only 1 row for user_id 3

if day_added matches with added_date then only include that data and do not include data with 'N/A'

SQL Fiddle is here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea5e39/2/0

Help will highly appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. You didn't specify which of the rows you *do* want to keep though so I'm assuming the non-N/A takes priority.

```
SELECT
    ...
    coalesce(c1.comments, c2.comments) as comments,
    ...
FROM
    users 
    LEFT JOIN comments c1
        ON     c1.user_id = users.id
           AND DATE_FORMAT(users.added_date,'%a') = c1.day_added
    LEFT JOIN comments c2
        ON     c2.user_id = users.id
           AND c2.day_added = 'N/A'
```

Comment: Awesome !, resolved my issue so cleanly. Thanks very much !.